# How to cut a fragment of text before special sign?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have example of string which I would like to cut before the sign "\n".
So I have (pay attention that after \n are spaces):

```
"23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2\n                                                                  
"
```

and I would like to have:

```
"23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2"
```

How to do it in ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
s.split("\n").first
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a help of the method [***`String#rstrip`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-rstrip)

> Returns a copy of str with trailing whitespace removed.

```
s = "23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2\n                                                                  
"
s.rstrip # => "23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2"
```

If you want to modify the receiver itself use the bang version [***`String#rstrip!`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-rstrip-21).

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic Yes.. as OP interested only to right side,thus I used specific method...

Answer (score 0):

just for more options and because I like using regex :) the same with [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
s = "23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2\n                                                                  
"
s.gsub(/\n.*\z/, '') # => "23 Very Long String: Extreme String 2"
```